# CSS: Odd and even doesn't fire?

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the background colour of elements on my page based on their odds and evens.

However, my CSS doesn't change the background colour at all and I don't understand why!

This is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvqkf7cv/)

And this is my CSS code:

```
.miles:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#af1f32; 
}

.miles:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f7b637;
}
```

I even tried this and still didn't work:

```
.ite .miles:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color:#af1f32; 
}

.ite .miles:nth-child(even) {
    background-color:#f7b637;
}
```

I also tried it this way with no success:

```
.miles:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color:#af1f32; 
}

.miles:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color:#f7b637;
}
```

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: They need to be sequential. So you need to do something like `.ite:nth-child(odd) .miles`

Comment: Please provide a minimal subset of your HTML directly in the question. Obviously you know that `.foo:nth-child(even)` means "a `.foo` which is **also** an even-numbered child", right?

Comment: Try reading your selector as English and see if it makes sense. For `.miles:nth-child(odd)`, the English is `an element which has class `.miles`, **and** is an odd-numbered child of its (immediate) parent". Is that what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try,

```
.ite:nth-child(odd) .miles {
    background-color:#af1f32; 
}

.ite:nth-child(even) .miles {
    background-color:#f7b637;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you are targeting the child element `.miles` whose parent element is `.ite` so that's why even and odd won't work as `.miles` are first element of `.ite`, so better use `nth-child(even) and (odd)` on parent element `.ite` and then target `inner elements` could be any.

```css
.ite:nth-child(odd) .miles{
    background-color:#af1f32; 
}

.ite:nth-child(even) .miles{
    background-color:#f7b637;
}
```

```html
<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>


<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are applying odd and even to .miles class but the thing is .ite class contains only one .miles class that's why its was showing only odd background color.
here is the sample.
thank you.

```css
.ite:nth-child(odd) .miles{
    background-color:#af1f32; 
}

.ite:nth-child(even) .miles {
    background-color:#f7b637;
}
```

```html
<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>



<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>


<div class="ite" id="" align="center" style="position:relative;width:90%; min-height:70px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#fff;">
<div class="miles" style="width:20%; height:70px; padding:5px; float:left; color:#fff; font-size:1.3em; position:relative;">
25 miles
</div>

<div style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#000; font-size:1.2em; text-align:left;">
some Name
<p style=" width:70%; height:auto; padding:5px; background-color:white; float:left; color:#ccc; font-size:1em; padding:0; margin:0;">
Street Name<br>
City, Zip
</p>

</div>
</div>
```